# Specifying coordinates in tikzcd arrows with a foreach loop

Tags: foreach, tikz-cd

I'm trying to use a foreach loop to draw a whole bunch of arrows in a tikzcd environment by using the foreach loop to specify coordinates but I can't get it to compile. Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  A & B & C \\
  \foreach \x in {2,3}{
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-\x]
  }
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Which should appear as an arrow from A to B and another from A to C. Instead I'm recieving this error:

ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---

pgf@sh@ns@\tikzcdmatrixname -1-\x

l.12 \end{tikzcd}

I think I could get it to work in a plain tikz environment but I'd like to use tikzcd if possible. Thanks for any help.

Comment: on your way it is not possible in `tikz-cd`.  compare your approach with standard `tikz-cd` syntax: `A \ar[r]& B\ar[r] & C` and you will see, that arrows there is modified (starting point is defined with cell where its command is placed and end in cell defined by option `r`. check the manual, if there is mentioned possibilities of what you like to have.

Comment: If I replace the code in the tikzcd environment with just `A & B \\ ` followed by `\arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2]` then it compiles correctly. The problem appears to be in putting the variable `\x` in as a coordinate.

Comment: do you try to direct arrow from the first cell directly to the last?  frankly said, i don't see any benefits with writing arrows on the your way. good luck in searching for solution which you like to obtain :-)

Comment: Yes, I should have said an arrow from A to B and an arrow from A to C. What I'm trying to do in the end is draw a cube diagram with 4x4x4 nodes made of lots of smaller cubes. There would be 144 arrows so I'd quite like to use foreach so I don't have to write them all out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with a `\draw` in `execute at end picture`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
    every matrix/.append style={name=mymatrix},
    execute at end picture={
        \foreach \x in {2,3}{
            \draw[->] (mymatrix-1-1) -- (mymatrix-1-\x);
        }
    }
]
  A & B & C \\
\end{tikzcd}

And Zarko's example:

\begin{tikzcd}[
    every matrix/.append style={name=mymatrix},
    execute at end picture={
         \foreach \x [count=\xx] in {2,3}{ \draw[->] (mymatrix-1-\xx) -- (mymatrix-1-\x); 
         }
    }
]
  A & B & C \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i'm glad to see, that i was wrong in my comment! to your example i would add the following example: `        \foreach \x [count=\xx] in {2,3}{
            \draw[->] (mymatrix-1-\xx) -- (mymatrix-1-\x);
        }
:-)  +1 for answer

Comment: thanks for your answer - this worked for me

Comment: i store your answer in my barn of tikz-cd solutions.  i very liked it!

Comment: @Zarko What an honor! :) Thanks

Comment: When delete `every matrix/.append style={name=mymatrix}` in the second environment, it still works. It seems that the same option in the first environment works globally. Is it designed to work like this?

Comment: @jiaopjie Interesting question! It seems to work globally but I don't know why. I think you could ask a question, a TikZ expert will surely answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical expansion problem.

The `\arrow` macro just takes everything between `[` and `]` and stores it as-is in a long list which gets processed much later. At that point `\x` isn't `2` or `3` anymore.

I provide three solutions:

1. An `\arrowx[<opt1>][<opt2>]` macro that expands `<opt1>` before it processes it. The `<opt2>` will get forwarded as-is and *not* expanded. That will only be really necessary when you have to use fragile node content.
2. The `\arloop{<opt>}{<list>}` macro uses a `\foreach` loop (i.e. the `...` syntax is allowed) over `<list>` to construct `\arrow[<opt>]` statements where `#1` in `<opt>` is replaced by the elements of your list.
3. The `end arrows` key that executes its argument directly (after the nodes have been constructed, of course) when there's no expansion issue anymore.

(The PGFPlots package also provides various ungrouped and/or invoking loop constructs but these seem easy enough to implement just for TikZ-CD.)

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{every diagram/.append code=\let\arrowx\tikzcd@arrowx\let\arloop\tikzcd@arloop}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzcd@arrowx}{O{}O{}}{%
  \edef\tikzcd@temp{#1}%
  \expandafter\arrow\expandafter[\expandafter{\tikzcd@temp,#2}]}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzcd@arloop}{mm}{%
  \pgfkeys{/utils/temp/.code=\arrow[{#1}],/utils/temp/.list={#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzcd@arrowlate}{O{}}{%
  \path[{/tikz/commutative diagrams/.cd,every arrow,#1}]
    (\tikzcd@ar@start\tikzcd@startanchor)to(\tikzcd@ar@target\tikzcd@endanchor);}
\tikzcdset{
  end arrows/.style={
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/every matrix/.append style={
      append after command=
        \pgfextra{\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\tikzcd@savedpaths{\let\arrow\tikzcd@arrowlate#1}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A & B & C
  \foreach \x in {2, 3}{
    \arrowx[from=1-1, to=1-\x, bend right]
  }
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzcd}
  A & B & C
  \arloop{from=1-1, to=1-#1, bend left}{2,3}
\end{tikzcd}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  end arrows={
    \foreach \x in {2, 3}{
      \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-\x, bend right]
    }
  }
]
  A & B & C
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]